# How to display php json response COUNT(e_u.med_id) in jquery

Tags: json, jquery

I m getting json reponse from php file`[{"med_name":"Test","COUNT(e_u.med_id)":"3"}]` using jquery ajax  which I want to display. How can I display COUNT(e_u.med_id) my jquery code is

```
 $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         url:'Myphp.php',
         data:{some-rec: 'test'},
         success:   function(rows){ 
         $('#e_use').empty();
          //alert("test");
         if(rows.success != false){
             $('#t_e_use').show();
             //alert("if");
            var len = rows.length;
            //alert(len);
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            $('#e_use').append("<tr><td style='color:#FFF'>"+
            rows[i].med_name
            +"</td><td style='color:#FFF'>"+
            COUNT(e_u.med_id)+
            "</td><tr>");
            }
        }
        else{
            $('#e_e_use').show();
        $('#e_e_use').text("No medicines are below the mandatory quantity");
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
rows[i]["COUNT(e_u.med_id)"];
```

but this is a strange variable name!!!

Comment: Thanks Samuel that worked for me I was actually counting the total times it was used in php mysql.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rows[i].COUNT(e_u.med_id)
```

instead of

```
COUNT(e_u.med_id)
```

**updated**

change `COUNT(e_u.med_id)` to  `count_emed_id` and take it as

```
rows[i].count_emed_id
```

Comment: try changing the name.... COUNT(e_u.med_id)  to "count_eumed_id"...and take it as `rows[i].count_eumed_id`.. i think it is because of the "." u have in `COUNT(e_u.med_id)`.

Comment: Yes, I think so too (I'm not the OP :)), it is just to point that this solution does not work as is...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. but please, change the variable name!

```
+"</td><td style='color:#FFF'>"+
rows[i]['COUNT(e_u.med_id)']+
"</td><tr>");
```